# Get ADB TCP connection log

Tags: adb, logging

I was wondering if there was a way to get the ADB connection log (on-device), for when someone types:

```
adb connect <IP>
```

with their IP

EDIT:
Kind of like with your `/var/log/auth.log` on Linux, where when someone `SSH`s into your server, you can check the `/var/log/auth.log` and see their IP

Answer (score 0):

first you need to connect the device to PC where you want to see logs via usb cable and allow the usb debugging fingerprints.

Than you can connect to the mobile via adb connect 
port : 5555 (used mostly)

Comment: The OP isn't asking *how* to connect.  The question is about how to get logs of such events.